# Distance between two positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Given two positive semidefinite matrices X, and Y. My question is, can we use von Neumann or the log-Determinant divergences to measure the distance between the two matrices. Most Manifold measure distance require two positive definite (PD) matrices.

In this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/yoshii13.pdf), the authors used the log-Determinant divergence with two positive semidefinite matrices (PSD). However, from what I know, the two divergences are for measures involving positive definite matrices (PD).

Any insight please.

Comment: Well, you can use the Frobenius norm, or any other matrix norm.
It is not clear why you want a distance on the PSD cone.

Comment: Thank you @Surb, the idea is Euclidian distance is not suited for measuring distance between PSD matrices and Riemannian metrics works only with PD matrices.